# Mex generates error for // while compiling C code in Linux

Tags: c, gcc, mex

I want to compile a C code in ubuntu using `mex` which is configured with gcc. I can smoothly compile the code in OSX. However, when I want to compile it in Linux, the compiler generates the error on the comment lines starting with `//` (it works fine with `/* */`. Since the program includes several header files from third-party libraries, I cannot substitute `//` with `/* */`.
I would like to know whether there is any way around to overcome this problem.

MATLAB version: R2012b
gcc version in Linux: 4.7.2
gcc version in OSX: 4.2.1

Any help is appreciated

Edit:
Here is the command I use to compile the code:

```
mex -g -largeArrayDims -ldl TDSVDHNGateway.c
```

Here is the error generated by mex:

```
In file included from TDSVDHNGateway.c:2:0:
TDS.h:17:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘/’ token
TDS.h:26:2: error: unknown type name ‘index_t’
TDS.h:27:2: error: unknown type name ‘index_t’
In file included from TDSVDHNGateway.c:2:0:
TDS.h:146:3: error: unknown type name ‘index_t’
TDSVDHNGateway.c:37:3: error: unknown type name ‘index_t’
TDSVDHNGateway.c: In function ‘mexFunction’:
TDSVDHNGateway.c:166:25: error: ‘index_t’ undeclared (first use in this function)
TDSVDHNGateway.c:166:25: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

Line 17 in header file is:

```
//Defining index_t
typedef size_t index_t;
```

If I replace `//Defining index_t` with `/*Defining index_t*/` the code will be compiled with no problem.

Comment: Can you list out the compiler errors?

Comment: Please determine and post the exact command line which `mex` uses to invoke `gcc`.  I suspect there is something in there which is disabling support for `//`-style comments (there are several options which do this (and other stuff as well)).

Comment: To allow C++ comments in C code call mex as follows: `mex CFLAGS="\$CFLAGS -Wp,-lang-c-c++-comments" mymexfile.c`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [the gcc docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Comments.html);

> In GNU C, you may use C++ style comments, which start with ‘//’ and continue until the end of the line. Many other C implementations allow such comments, and they are included in the 1999 C standard. **However, C++ style comments are not recognized if you specify an -std option specifying a version of ISO C before C99, or -ansi (equivalent to -std=c90).**

Under Linux, by default `mex` adds `-ansi`, which disables C++ comments. Either update your mexopts file, replacing `-ansi` with `-std=c99` or run mex with;

```
mex -g -largeArrayDims -ldl CFLAGS="\$CFLAGS -std=c99" TDSVDHNGateway.c
```